# Why only the first image is added to my dataframe in this loop?

Tags: python, regex, opencv

I am trying to read images from one directory and read their correspondant txt files containing the label and bounding box coordinates from another directory, then create a mask and store all these mask for each image in another dataframe.

The problem is only the first loop is executed in my code. (i.e in the mask_images dataset only the first image is stored)

here is my code:

```
mask_images = [] # DATASET FOR GRAYSCALE IMAGES
RGB_images = [] # DATASET FOR RGB IMAGES

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("dataset/test/images"):
    for imgname in filenames:
        if re.search("\.(jpg|jpeg|JPEG|png|bmp|tiff)$", imgname):
            imgpath = os.path.join(root, imgname)
            name = os.path.splitext(imgname)
            name = name[0] + ".txt"
            img = cv2.imread(imgpath)
            rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            RGB_images.append(rgb_image)
            mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype = np.uint8)
            #plt.imshow(mask, cmap = 'gray')
            #print(imgname)
            #print(imgpath)
            for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("dataset/test/detection_labels"):
                for txtname in filenames:
                    if name == txtname:
                        #print(txtname)
                        txtpath = os.path.join(root, txtname)
                        #print(txtpath)
                        with open(txtpath,'r') as f:
                            lines = f.readlines()
                            print(lines)
                            for line in lines:
                                #print(line)
                                coords = [float(coords) for coords in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', line)]
                                coords[1] = np.int_(coords[1] * 2000)
                                coords[2] = np.int_(coords[2] * 2000)
                                coords[3] = np.int_(coords[3] * 2000)
                                coords[4] = np.int_(coords[4] * 2000)
                                print(coords)
                                mask = cv2.rectangle(mask, pt1 = (coords[1], coords[2]), pt2 = (coords[1] + coords[3], coords[2] + coords[4]), color = (255,255,255), thickness = -1)
                            f.close()
            mask_images.append(mask)
```

Comment: Offtopic: you don't need to use `f.close()` when using `with open()`; it's done automatically.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Any idea how to solve the problem with loops?

Comment: Do the proper values get printed out, or only the first item as you mentioned? Also, what does the directory structure for images look like? Are the paths correct?

Comment: basically at the end of these loops, the mask_images dataframe contains only one item (i.e only mask_images[0] can be printed out and for others such as mask_images[1], I get this error "list index out of range")

Comment: I mean _inside_ the loop, are you getting all the images and labels you are expecting, or only the first?

Comment: the same problem exist with the other dataset (RGB_images). SO, I think only the first one

Comment: I would recommend you employ a debugger to step through your code to see where the issue lies.

Comment: When you reach 8 levels of indentation, it's a sign you ought to refactor your code a bit. Doing so will make it much easier to reason about it and test it.